# После ajax не видно изменений

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Редактирую данные ,все работает,все обновляет,но,после обновления нужно обновить страницу,чтобы увидеть результат,`alert` же сразу показывается без обновления

```
    $("body").on("click", "#editable .edit_btn", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

var newhead_note=$('#e_head').val();
var newtext_note=$('#e_text').val();
var this_edit_id_note=$('#id_note_hidden').val(); 

 var myData = "edit_id="+this_edit_id_note+"&newhead_note="+newhead_note+"&newtext_note="+newtext_note; //post variables
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP метод  POST или GET
            url: "ed.php", //url-адрес, по которому будет отправлен запрос
            dataType:"text", // Тип данных
            data:myData, //post переменные
            success:function(update){
            // в случае успеха, скрываем, выбранный пользователем для удаления, элемент
            $("#itog").html(update);
            alert("успех");

            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //выводим ошибку
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
  });
```

PHP

```
elseif(isset($_POST["edit_id"])&&strlen($_POST["newhead_note"])>0&&strlen($_POST["newtext_note"])>0){
include 'config.php';
$this_edit_id_note=$_POST['edit_id'];
$newhead_note=$_POST['newhead_note'];
$newtext_note=$_POST['newtext_note'];
$sqlupdate ="UPDATE note SET head='". $newhead_note."', text='".$newtext_note."' WHERE id='".$this_edit_id_note."'";
 $query = mysql_query($sqlupdate); 
echo $sqlupdate;
}
```

Comment: и что, в алерте написано `Успех`? ......обновить страницу `location.href = ВАШ_URL`

Comment: мне не очень понятно, вы заполняете #itog ответом сервера, а присылаете оттуда текст запроса?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да успех,мне без обновление необходимо

Comment: @zkolya вы понимаете что `,но,после обновления нужно обновить страницу` и ваше `мне без обновление необходимо` немного не уживаются вместе?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский,не,тут видимо,действительно,проблема в том,что я делаю при успешном запросе,необходимо видимо,заново формировать запрос на вывод и выводить данные

Comment: @zkolya либо при помощи js удалять блок. если вы например напишите $("#itog").hide(), то увидите разницу без обновления страницы. И удалять правильнее, если объем списка большой

Comment: @splash58, теперь они не нажимаются после $("#itog").hide(), не подскажите как сделать правильнее,что бы выводилось без перезагрузки?

Comment: ну как я вам подскажу, не зная структуры документа. выбираете элементы, которые должны быть удалены при успехе и так и говорите им `).remove()` раз вы пользуетесь jquery

Comment: @splash58,А в php получается,необходимо заново формировать запрос на вывод из базы,после обновления?

Comment: @zkolya ну да, полностью формировать страницу или ее часть